# how to use onMounted to do async things in Nuxt 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I don't know what's wrong with this, the `repository` ref's value just don't get updated

I wrote async/await, but it seems not working. `repository` is an empty array.

**I can use the api out of `onMounted`**, so I think its something wrong about it. I don't know much about it.

Here's my code:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Starred Repositories</h1>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="repository in repositories" :key="repository.id">
        <h3>{{ repository.name }}</h3>
        <p>{{ repository.description }}</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button @click="nextPage" :disabled="isLastPage">Next Page</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { Octokit } from '@octokit/core';

const repositories = ref([]);
const page = ref("1")
const runtimeConfig = useRuntimeConfig();

const octokit = new Octokit({
  auth: runtimeConfig.githubToken,
});

const nextPage = () => {
  page.value++;
}

onMounted(async () => {
  const response = await octokit.request('GET /user/starred?page=' + page.value, {
    headers: {
      'X-GitHub-Api-Version': '2022-11-28',
    },
  });
  repositories.value = response.data;
})

console.log(repositories.value);
</script>
```

also here's my app.vue:

```js
<script>
import Star from './components/Star.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    Star,
    }
}
</script>

<template>
  <Star />
</template>
```

Comment: "repository is an empty array" - how do you test for that? Do you mean `repositories`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your console log will execute and log an empty array because it will be executed before the code in `onMounted`, it is a hook and hooks don't themselves honour an async.

Move your `console.log` so it is inside the `onMounted` hook and also make sure the endpoint is infact retuning something other than an empty array it's self.

---

On a side note, using a life cycle hook for triggering API calls is not the best way, instead use the **Top Level Await & Watch** strategy.

https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/data-fetching#watch

In your case you are not using Nuxt's fetch helpers... so manual rigging looks like this:

```js
<script setup>

import { Octokit } from '@octokit/core';

const repositories = ref([]);
const page = ref(1)
const runtimeConfig = useRuntimeConfig();

const octokit = new Octokit({
  auth: runtimeConfig.githubToken,
});

const nextPage = () => {
  page.value++;
}


const fetchStarredUsers = async (page) => {
  const response = await octokit.request(`GET /user/starred?page=${page}`, {
    headers: {
      'X-GitHub-Api-Version': '2022-11-28',
    },
  });

  if(Array.isArray(response?.data)) {
    repositories.value = response.data
    return
  }
  
  console.error('Invalid response, expected array of users').
}

// Call on entering component, (triggers loading suspense)
// https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/data-fetching#suspense
await fetchStarredUsers(page.value)

// Call on page being changed
watch(page, fetchStarredUsers)

</script>
```